# Is it possible to do code analysis of an iOS framework?

Tags: ios, frameworks, sonarqube, swiftlint

I have a requirement where we need to perform code analysis to find vulnerabilities like how sonarqube does for an iOS Project, not for the actual swift files but for **.framework** created using the swift files.

Is it possible to do this using sonarqube or swiftlint? Are there any code analysis tool available to analyse the **.framework**?